# How to select data from one table that doesn't have any value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with my queries (using SQL Developer). This might be simple case but I have troubles with my thinking... so I have two tables GROUP and PERSON. I need to select all the group which don't have any males in them. So the SQL should return to me in this case only GROUP_NAME of Dogs (GROUP_ID = 2) as they have only females in them. I appreciate all the help!

So table1 GROUP:

[image]

and table2 PERSON:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the groups where there are no males you can use an `OUTER JOIN` from the groups to only the male people and then find the groups where there is no match:

```sql
SELECT g.*
FROM   "GROUP" g
       LEFT OUTER JOIN person p
       ON (p.group_id = g.group_id AND p.sex = 'Male')
WHERE  p.group_id IS NULL;
```

If you want to find the groups when there is at least one female and no males then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   "GROUP" g
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   person p
         WHERE  p.group_id = g.group_id
         AND    sex = 'Female'
       )
AND    NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   person p
         WHERE  p.group_id = g.group_id
         AND    sex = 'Male'
       )
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   "GROUP" g
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   person p
         WHERE  p.group_id = g.group_id
         HAVING COUNT(CASE sex WHEN 'Female' THEN 1 END) > 0
         AND    COUNT(CASE sex WHEN 'Male'   THEN 1 END) = 0
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer with multiple modifications. The second SQL was the one that worked best in my case but the others are very beneficial tips as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT G.GROUP_ID,G.GROUP_NAME
FROM GROUP G
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM PERSON P WHERE G.GROUP_ID=P.GROUP_ID AND P.SEX='MALE'
)
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.group_id
from group a, person b
where a.group_id=b.group_id and
group by a.group_id having COUNT(CASE b.sex WHEN 'male' THEN 1 END)=0 and
                      COUNT(CASE b.sex WHEN 'female' THEN 1 END)>0
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_NAME
FROM GROUP_TABLE g
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM PERSON p WHERE SEX = 'male' AND p.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID)
```